# In rails, what does form_for point to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

so I have this piece of code:

```
<%= form_for(:player, :url => {:action => 'pedal_to_player', :id => @pedal.id}) do |x| %>
```

so my question is: how did I get `:player`?  what is is linkin to? a controller? a model?

P.S. in my controller I have:

```
def add_player
  @pedal = Pedal.find(params[:id])
  @player = BassGuy.new  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

this form will send its data to:

```
params[:player]
```

its a nested hash that will contain all data that the user typed in the form